# Avoid wget command timeout

Tags: wget

Im running a `wget` command via bash script that i have and it keeps getting `connection timed out` response, I don't want the `wget` to retry and just run once. how can I stop that:

`HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection timed out) in headers.
Retrying.`

Answer (score 0):

Use the  -t number
       --tries=number flag set to 1

Comment: AS I understand it it will only retry once  - Set number of retries to number.  Specify 0 or inf for infinite retrying.  The default is to retry 20 times, with
           the exception of fatal errors like "connection refused" or "not found" (404), which are not retried.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider switching to curl.